# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\Big)^2=|f'(r)|^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can anyone help with this:

Let $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $u=f(r)$,where $r=\|x\|$ and f is differentiable .

Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\Big)^2=|f'(r)|^2$ .
I can't get how to solve it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(r)}{\partial x_i} 
&= f'(r) \cdot \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} 
 = f'(r) \cdot \frac{\partial \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}}{\partial x_i} \\
&= f'(r) \cdot \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}} \\
&= f'(r) \cdot \frac{x_i}{r}
\end{align}

Your LHS is then
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \right)^2 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( f'(r) \cdot \frac{x_i}{r} \right)^2 
 = \left( \frac{f'(r)}{r} \right)^2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \\
&= \left( \frac{f'(r)}{r} \right)^2 \cdot r^2
 = f'(r)^2 = |f'(r)|^2
\end{align}

QED

Try to avoid unnecessary symbols btw, they make the problem look more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: It would be so kind of  you if you could help me understanding how did you directly wrote $f'(r)^2 = |f'(r)|^2$....

Comment: I assumed the image set of $f$ to be (a subset of) $\mathbb{R}$ because, from everything you provided, there was no reason not to do so and the domain is $\mathbb{R}_0^+$. Thus, $f'$ is real-valued too. $|x|^2 = x^2$ holds for any real number.

Comment: thanks for explaining.....

Comment: You do not appear satisfied..... why is that..... ?

Comment: I am confused a bit on understanding $f'(r)$...It seems to me a function rather than a no.

Comment: For any given $r$, function $f'$ takes some fixed real value. All laws of real number arithmetics apply.